# Can't run IOS tests for Kotlin Multi Plateform Mobile app

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I just installed the KMM plugin on Android Studio to create a multi plateform mobile app. I followed all the steps in the doc https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-create-first-app.html#run-your-application-on-android but when I tried to run the test for IOS, I received "No tasks avaiable". Someone has the same issue than me ?
I work on a Mac Book air M1 computer and I have Xcode installed ( both emulation for android and IOS works ).
THX !
[image]

Comment: Please clarify, you can start the application directly from the AS, but the tests don't work correctly?

Comment: Yes the app start but when I tried to run IOS or Android tests, I recevied "No tasks available". Only common tests works

Comment: What Android Studio and Kotlin/KMM plugin versions do you use?

Comment: Android 2020.3.1 and KMM 0.2.7

Comment: I've found a similar issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-8859, where it is stated that the problem should be gone with AS Bumblebee 2021.1.1. Could you please give it a try?

Comment: for some reason I don't have the update :x " No IDE or plugin updates avaibles"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that Bumblebee is still in beta, so it won't install from the stable channel. Probably, you will have to download it from the Android Studio website manually.